# How to set content-type without charset? (Apache Tomcat)

Tags: java, apache, tomcat7, mime-types, servlet-filters

I was trying to set content-type -> "application/pkcs7-mime" of a file (file dont have any extension). I tried using Filter and

```
servletResponse.setContentType("application/pkcs7-mime;");
```

but i am getting "application/pkcs7-mime;charset=ISO-8859-1" in content-type in httpheader.

I also tried adding "mime-mapping" in web.xml but since file don't have any extension, mime-mapping tag is not working. tried these two possible

```
<mime-mapping> 
    <extension>*</extension> 
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-excel</mime-type> 
</mime-mapping>
```

and

```
<mime-mapping> 
    <extension>.</extension> 
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-excel</mime-type> 
</mime-mapping>
```

I think mime-mapping only works with files which have extensions.
Is it possible to remove charset from content-type in Filter? or is it possible to do same using web.xml?

Comment: What is wrong with the charset, `ISO-8859-1` is the default one.

Comment: i know its default charset, but file i am using is a domain verification file for apple store. Which don't allow charset in content-type.

Comment: Try `setCharacterEncoding(String encoding)` with null or empty String, I have no idea if it's gonna work tho, just idea.

Comment: Nope, i tried null and empty string.. not working :(